# How to set multiline text in floated div not expand his width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I want use floatet image with some text about this image in my content.

I'm using this HTML + CSS for this:

```
<p class="container">
<img src="http://www.google.com.ua/images/logos/ps_logo2.png" width="200"/>
<span class="text">Some text wider that image image image blablabla</span>
```

And CSS for it:

```
.container { float:right; border:2px solid #000; }
.container img { display:block; margin-bottom:10px; }
```

But, if text about image is wider, it is expand floated parent. I'm not want this behaviour. I want to limit max-width of parent p element to width of image.

Here example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wBVqt/1/

I can do what I want through position:absolute and padding-bottom, but I don't know value for padding-bottom. jsfiddle.net/wBVqt/3/

Answer (score 1):

I don't see solution with only css if you want to have images of different sizes, so chek my [solution with jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/wBVqt/10/):

```
var imageWidth = 0;
$('.container img').each(function(index, el){
    if(el.width > imageWidth) {
        imageWidth = el.width;
    }
});
imageWidth = imageWidth ? imageWidth : '100%';

$('.container').css('width', imageWidth);
```

It will work yet if you have a lot of images in your container. If you have no images, it will set originally 100% width to container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just putting a width on the container? (Which you should do anyway if you want your code to validate, as all floated elemets should have a width).

```
.container { float:right; border:2px solid #000; width: 200px; }
```

Comment: I don't know width, image has different width. Where did you read, that all floated elements should have a width?

Comment: Your CSS will validate without puttin width on your floats, but it is best practice to do so. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/